# How to distinguish Debug, Release and Unit Test source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to write a piece of source code like this:

```
log(bDebug=true, bRelease=false, bUnitTesting=true, <some information>);
```

This piece of code should do the following:

- bDebug : the logging needs to be done in case this piece of code is called in "Debug" mode.
- bRelease : this logging needs to be done in case this piece of code is called in "Release" mode.
- bUnitTesting : this logging needs to be done in case this piece of code is called during unit testing (defined in a standard Visual Studio Native Unit Test project).

I already am aware of the `#define Debug` (or capitals, I'm not sure) which I can use for switching between "Debug" and "Release" builds, but I have no idea if there are any `#define` clauses for Unit Test projects. (Or is there another way to know this?)

Just for giving you more information: I already have a class `Logger` which takes care of logging information, but I know that the Microsoft framework also has a `Logger` class, doing this for unit tests (`Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Logger`). Is there a way to switch between application logging and unit test logging?

Comment: You can have any "`#define`" in your build system (as it is done in your template for debug/release).

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to perform printf-debugging.

Comment: It is possible than your framework does some `#define`.

Comment: It is better to pass enum which is structured such that you can use bitwise operator to find what and all logging is set.

Comment: Distinguishing between Debug and release is easy enough as as you say.      If I was working on a project that used unit testing, I'd be deeply concerned about any function that can DETECT if unit testing is underway - since such a function could also be explicitly coded to give false passes or fails of unit tests.   Consider the behaviour of firmware used by Volkswagen to cheat regulated emission testing of their diesel engines, by operating in a different mode when it detected being run in a test setting.

Comment: #define might not work in your situation, using dependency injection would be a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077884/9125096